# Why doesn't python3 care about non-ascii characters in source file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

Suppose I have a .py file with the following contents

```
print('(ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻')
```

When called by python3 it prints the angry guy flipping a table, however on python2 we get `SyntaxError` and need to add a declaration line like `# coding: utf-8` in the file to run it.

My question is why doesn't python 3 care about non-ascii characters?  I don't see any description of that in [PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).  How does the interpreter guess the encoding of the file correctly when I didn't specify that, where is the behaviour documented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Python 3 uses `utf-8` as the default source code encoding](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

Python 2 [uses `ASCII` by default](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#encodings), so unless you explicitly tell Python `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file, it doesn't know how to handle character values above 127.